# How to create check a conversation created or not? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a chat system. I have db structure like bellow.

```
conversations
    id
    type

participants
    conversation_id
    user_id

users
    id
    name
```

User model and Conversation have Many-to-Many relationship. What I would like to know is how to know if a conversation is already existed or not between given ids. If I have **$user_ids=[1, 2, 3]**, I would like to know that they are already under same conversation id or not.
**Note:** Some users may have multiple same conversations because I have group chat function. "type" column on conversations table is flag for being group chat or not.
This is what I am trying.

```
$conversation = Conversation::whereHas("users", function($user) use($user_ids){
    $user->where("users.id", $user_ids);
})->where("type", 1)->first();
```

But the problem is I am still getting the conversation even all of given user ids are not in participants table.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a chain of [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
foreach ($user_ids as $user_id)
{
    $query=$query->whereHas("users", function($query) use($user_id){
        $query->where("users.id", $user_id);
    });
}
$conversation=$query->firstWhere("type", 1);
```

Comment: I want to reduce query as much as possible. There are over 100,000 conversations. I'm working with existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your life easier by making use of the `belongsToMany`eloquent relationship method?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function conversations()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Conversations::class, 'participants', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');
    }
}
```

And then you can easily check for those conversations like so:

```php
<?php
$conversations = Auth::user()->conversations;
foreach($conversations as $conversation) {
   // insert your logic here.
}
?>
```

Read more about it in Laravel's official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Yes. I used. That's why I said that it was Many-to-Many relationship. Also what I want to do is to check conversation existed or not. Not how many conversations are there for a user.